# Ember select is not showing the selected item

Tags: javascript, object, ember.js, ember-select

I know there is a small problem staring right at my face by can't figure it out.

Consider

```
{{view Ember.Select                         
     content=baseList          
     optionLabelPath="content.desc"
     optionValuePath="content.id"
     selectionBinding="selectedItem" 
 }}

baseList = [{"id":"item1","desc":"item number is 1"},{"id":"item2","desc":"item number is 2"}]
```

Below does not work

```
selectedItem = {"id":"item1","desc":"item number is 1"};
```

The select drop down does not show any selected item

Below works

```
selectedItem = baseList.filterBy('id','item1')[0];
```

Now the select drop down shows the selected item.

What is the problem? I even checked if the order of the properties(id and desc) are proper. Is it because two objects cant be compared directly unless certain algorithm is employed or rather use `JSON.stringify`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you specify

```
selectedItem = {"id":"item1","desc":"item number is 1"};
```

that hash is a different object from the one in `baseList`, even though it's lexically identical. So Ember cannot find it in `baseList` (it's doing a `===` compare, not a deep compare). When you do the `filterBy`, on the other hand, it returns the actual object from within `baseList`, which `Ember.Select` can then find in `baseList`.

You might want to try using `valueBinding` instead; then you can just specify `"item1"`.

BTW, the order of properties makes no difference here or anywhere else in JS.

Comment: "that hash is a different object from the one in baseList" Thought so.
<br/>
Thanks a lot "valueBinding" is what i was looking for.
<br/>
" the order of properties", i think u will find it does especially when you are doing JSON.stringify and then comparing. However in that case it will be more of a string comparison.
<br/>
Overall you are right. Thanks a ton